How to say/Is it correct to say "If I may ask"?
Say I am speaking with a person, and I want to know where they are from,

Where are you originally from? If I may ask?

Is the above expression idiomatic?, particularly the If I may ask part.
What are the other ways of saying the same thing?

It would be more idiomatic to make it all one sentence.

Where are you originally from, if I may ask?

If I may ask is not a proper sentence on its own. You could also put it before the question, at the beginning of the sentence. Another version is if you don't mind me asking.
